# JS align each column dynamically based on data

Tags: javascript

There is a message recieved from the backend which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "ColumnType": "NUMBER"
    },
    {
        "Name": "XYZ",
        "ColumnType": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "Name": "EFG",
        "ColumnType": "NUMBER"
    },
    {
        "Name": "JKL",
        "ColumnType": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "Name": "TOP",
        "ColumnType": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    
]
```

The "Name" is used as the column name in the table and the data in the column is aligned w.r.t the column type i.e For a ColumnType "NUMBER" and "TIMESTAMP" right align and for ColmnType "STRING" left align.

I have tried the following,

```
 var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
        let tdArr = Array.from(td);
        for (var item in snapshot) {
          let DataHeader = snapshot[item].DataHeader;
          for(let x in DataHeader){
              let colType = snapshot[item].DataHeader[x].columnType;
                 for(let z in tdArr){
                    if(colType === 'STRING' && colType !== 'NUMBER'){
                      tdArr[z].style.textAlign= "left";
                    }
                    else if(colType === 'NUMBER' && colType !== 'STRING'){
                      tdArr[z].style.textAlign= "right";
                    }
                    else if(colType === 'TIMESTAMP'){
                      tdArr[z].style.textAlign= "right";
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
```

This however sets all tds to either right align or left align. How do I work around this? I know I'm setting all td elements and I'm not sure how I can grab td elements of a particular column.

The above shown message is part of a snapshot object which has a DataHeader. The DataHeader contains the "Name" and the "ColumnType".

Comment: Where did you place Name in DOM, show that part

Comment: You could loop over all tds first instead of again and again in the inner loop. So loop once over all tds. For every td you assign a style (or add a class, however you like) based on the data type.

Comment: @Greg-- I have used v-data-table from vuetify, pushed the names into an array called col_list and set :headers="col_list" in v-data-table.

Comment: @PeterKrebs the columType is only for the th not the tds

Comment: Add class to td whan you put names on it

Comment: @Draco So you're saying if you know which column you are in you know which style to apply. Oh see answer below, they are using `:nth-of-type` and just loop once over the tds.

Comment: "columType is only for the th not the tds" - but based on the columnType the alignment of the tds is set? Please have a look at my answer below and let me know if/why it might not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

When using .forEach() or .map() you get the index as second parameter, which can be very helpful

```js
let columnInfos = [
    {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "ColumnType": "NUMBER"
    },
    {
        "Name": "XYZ",
        "ColumnType": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "Name": "EFG",
        "ColumnType": "NUMBER"
    }
]

columnInfos.forEach((columnInfo, index) => {

  let columnType = columnInfo.ColumnType

  let tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`td:nth-of-type(${index+1})`))

  if(columnType === 'NUMBER' || columnType === 'TIMESTAMP') {
    tds.forEach(td => td.style.textAlign = 'right')
  }else if(columnType === 'STRING'){
    tds.forEach(td => td.style.textAlign = 'right')
  }
})
```